# Is there a concise way to write a set of enums as strings?

Tags: javascript

When i write enums in javascript I often write:

```
const movementState = {
  stopped: 'stopped',
  walking: 'walking',
  running: 'running',
};
```

This enables me to use it like `movementState.stopped` and linting ensures it exists, also if I log it, it's value is human readable.

I'd like something like:

```
enum movementState = {stopped, walking, running};
```

Note: I have no interest in doing this in typescript. I do my survival work-job in TS, I do my passion in JS.

I'm not super up to date w the standard... so I was hoping maybe something new was added in one of the stages or something. Thanks~

Comment: `{stopped, walking, running}` is shorthand for `{stopped: stopped, walking: walking, running: running}`. It uses the property names as variables, not as strings.

Comment: What you're doing is probably still the best way to do it. If you don't like the repetition, you could also use [symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) as values, but that's not any more concise, and the values are not human readable when you log them out, unless you bring the repition back in (by providing a symbol description).

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to map an array of the strings to an array of entries, using the string as the value and as the key, then turn it into an object with `Object.fromEntries`. Not extraordinarily concise, but I'm not sure if you can get anything better.

```js
const makeEnum = strs => Object.fromEntries(
  strs.map(str => [str, str])
);

const movementState = makeEnum(['stopped', 'walking', 'running']);
console.log(movementState.running);
```